# MVC - View as iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, html-helper, action-filter

I'm fairly new to MVC and I'd like to know if it is somehow possible to create a custom Action Filter like for example "ChildAction", to allow a view to be called by an iFrame.

For example:

```
[IframeAction] // Custom attribute
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Embeddable (){ // Only accessible if called by an iframe
    return View();
}
```

Thank you in advance for any possible help.

Best Regards,

Kevin

## **EDITED**

So far the code I have is:

```
public class IframeActionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["iframe"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request) && request.Equals("true"))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is used as the example I provided before, and it checks if the request string has the param: iframe set to true

Embed example:

```
<iframe src="@string.Format("{0}embed/{1}?iframe=true", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["App:BaseUri"], Model)"></iframe>
```

Is this the way to go or is there a better approach?

Comment: The term is _create an Action Filter_ :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the tip, fixed the question :)

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179333/detect-if-a-page-is-within-a-iframe-serverside)  - you can check the query string value in the filter

Comment: I see, thank you for your help :D